# I'd like to understand this assert macro

Tags: c++, macros

In Visual Studio the assert macro is defined like this:

```
#define assert(expression) (void)(                                                       \
            (!!(expression)) ||                                                              \
            (_wassert(_CRT_WIDE(#expression), _CRT_WIDE(__FILE__), (unsigned)(__LINE__)), 0) \
        )
```

I get that the right part after || is only evaluated if the left expression is false, and throws an exception.

I have 3 questions:

1. The !! double negation is to convert the 'expression' type to bool, right? What would happen if they were left out? The 'expression would be implicitly converted to bool when it's logically or'ed with another expression, right? In:

   float() || /* Call function that throws*/;

The float() is converted to bool type anyway?

2.After the || operator we have:

```
 ( /* call function that throws */  , 0 )
```

The comma is a sequence point, so first the function is called and then this expression is evaluated as 0. If the function call didn't terminate the program then the expression would simply be:

```
!!(expression)) || 0
```

What's the point of that 0 after the comma? If if weren't there, then the expression would be:

```
!!(expression)) || / * call function that throws */
```

Which is the same thing, right?

3. And finally the (void), I'm wondering what this is for.

Comment: What if I have a type that has (foolishly? let's give benefit of a doubt and presume for good reason) overridden `operator||` ?  Hmm, probably a `((bool)(expression) || ...` would have been safer.  They also may have overridden `operator!`.

Comment: The comma operator is needed because `_wassert` returns a `void`.  And [`_wassert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/assert-macro-assert-wassert) doesn't `throw`, it either aborts with exit code 3, breaks into the debugger, or ignores the issue and continues.  It's behavior can be changed with `_set_error_mode`.  The macro also dodges the dangling else problem using a macro with an `if` statement, and is a bit clever because it keeps it as an *expression* rather than a *statement*.

Comment: The top most level `(void)` is to squelch the compiler warning for an unused *expression* result, and also protects against accidentally using the expression result.  And the macro is probably the same one used when compiling as C or C++ or C++/CLI, so has to meet the intersection of those languages.

Comment: @Eljay, cool, now make it an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down the code:

```
#define assert(expression) (void)(                                                       \
            (!!(expression)) ||                                                              \
            (_wassert(_CRT_WIDE(#expression), _CRT_WIDE(__FILE__), (unsigned)(__LINE__)), 0) \
        )
```

The `(void)` is to squelch the compiler warning that the expression result is unused.  And also ensures that the assert is not accidentally used as part of a larger expression.

The `!!` part of the `!!(expression)` is to ensure that the expression evaluates to `false` or `true`.

But mischievous C++ code could have overridden `operator!` and cause a bit of chaos here.

Why C-style cast, and not `static_cast<bool>`?  I suspect the same header file is used to support C and C++, and possibly C++/CLI as well.  (If so, could be justification to use `static_cast<bool>` for C++, and `(bool)` for C in two language specific macros.)

If the `expression` object has an `operator bool` conversion, it will be used by the `!!`.  (But would also have been used by `(bool)(expression)`.)

Regardless, the observation that the `!!` is unnecessary seems correct to me.  Expressions in C++ that are *truthy* (non-zero) or *falsy* (zero) is part-and-parcel to the language.

The `(x(), 0)` comma operator is used because the `x` (in this case the `_wassert`) returns a void.  Can't do an `a || b` if the `b` is void, so the trickery just makes it so the void is called, and the expression results in an `int`.  It does not matter that it is `0`.

The [`_wassert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/assert-macro-assert-wassert) does not throw.  It may abort with exit code 3.  It may break into the debugger.

It may be ignored and continue.  And with the assert having been violated there could be a broken axle consequences, or the code may have some defensive programming to handled the assert violation.

Since the assert function-like macro was written as an *expression*, it neatly avoids the problem of the "dangling `if` macro" (had an `if (!(expression)) ...` construct been used), and is an *expression* rather than a *statement*.